# Possible to limit returned results by multiple values

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I'm a little miffed with this one, i have a list of customers coming from a query:

```
IQueryable<Customer> Customers()
{
 return myDc.Customers;
}
```

This returns all the customers.

The `Customers` table has two additional columns, **Risk** and **Status**. Risk tells us what risk we have with that customer and Status tells us what state their account is under.

The user has a search page where they select multiple Risk and Statuses. I capture their **selected values** into a `List` of integers and would like to pass that into my query above.

Since the user can select multiple Risk values (and Statuses) if i have a `foreach` around the `Customers` query it doesnt get all the Risks the user selected i.e.

```
foreach (int r in RisksList)
{
  return Customers.Where(r=> r.Risk.Tostring().Contains(r.ToString());
}
```

When the above query executes it limits it to the first Risk found, but any other Risks contained within RisksList is not captured.

I would be doing the same with Statuses (once i have the correct Risks records).

How could i limit all the customers found by the integer values contained within `RisksList` (and then limit the `StatusList`)?

Edit 1

```
    IQueryable<Customer> customers = from c in myDc.Customers select c;

    foreach (int i in RisksList)
    {
        customers = from cc in customers where (RisksList.Contains(i)) select cc;
    }
```

Comment: I would rename the `r` because it is the same variable in the `foreach` and in the lambda expression

Comment: What do you expect return to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When the above query executes it limits it to the first Risk found,
>   but any other Risks contained within RisksList is not captured.

That's because of your `return` statement inside your loop.

Instead of returning the results, you can add it to a result list, or you could try that cleaner way :

```
return Customers.Where(r=> RiskLists.Contains(r.Risk));
```

The same for your other lists.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have made a change whilst i was waiting listed under Edit 1. This gives me the entire customer list instead of limiting it?

Comment: My sample will give you all `Customers` having a `Risk` contained inside `RiskLists`

Answer (score 1):

Remove `foreach` and just use this.

```
return Customers.Where(r=> RisksList.Any(x=> r.Risk.ToString().Contains(x.ToString()));
```